# How swap between cells on a single column in css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

Im making a responsive behaviour to my site. Its a simple grid of 2 columns and auto rows with various items. I added this to make it to only 1 column at 890px:

```
@media all and (max-width: 890px) {
.main-container div {
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}}
```

Then they do it nicely. The problem its that I had 14 items in that grid. And I want at this point that the .item6 goes where the .item7 is, and the other way around.
I tried to add "order:x" to the items and changing that order when the screen its at 890px but doesnt work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6RpK.png)

Here u can see better, the .item6 is another wall of text. The next item (.item7) its a picture. I want that .item7 to be placed where .item6 is. Swap its positions. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Using "grid-row:n".